# vector of structs giving error "not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector, struct, initialization

I have a struct declared as follows:

```
#ifndef PLAYLIST_H
#define PLAYLIST_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "playlistitem.h"
#include "song.h"
#include "time.h"
struct Playlist {
    std::vector<Song> songs;
    Time cdTotalTime;
    int totalTime;
};
```

and struct Song declared in another file:

```
#ifndef SONG_H
#define SONG_H
#include "playlist.h"
#include "time.h"
struct Song {
    std::string title;
    std::string artist;
    std::string album;
    int track;
    Time length;
};
```

I have both struct definitions in headers, and both are #included as they should be.

When I compile I get an error at

```
std:vector<Song> songs;
```

> error 'Song' was not declared in this scope

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have included the `Song`'s definition file in the file, defining `Playlist` ? And that it's in the same namespace?

Comment: How are you "including them as they should be"? (Hint: You're not ;) )

Comment: Please show us the file where you use the definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

playlist.h includes song.h

song.h should NOT include playlist.h

Header guards prevent infinite recursion, they don't fix circular dependencies.

Currently song.h does include playlist.h.  Then when playlist.h includes song.h, nothing happens (because of the header guard), and `Song` is not defined.  So playlist.h produces errors.

Answer (score 1):

Not only your main file, but the file where `Playlist` is declared should also #include the file where `Song`  is in.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `Song` has to come before its used in the definition of `Playlist`. Since they are in different headers, you should make sure that the header for `Playlist` includes that of `Song`, and both have proper header guards.

Answer (score 0):

Your headers include each other in circular fashion. This is useless and unnecessary. Why is your `song.h` including `playlist.h`? Remove `#include "playlist.h"` from `song.h` and that should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could prototype `Song` in your header by putting `struct Song;` and just include the header in your .c/.cpp file. This has the bonus of faster compile times! :D

Recursive includes work fine with include guards, as long as you arrange them properly. I always try and include the least amount of headers in .h files, leaving them for the source files.

Also, I don't see a #endif on your code. Right now I'm assuming your code actually has it ;)